# Move an <img> when button pressed

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code that I am currently using for the function, I have made `img`s move in the past using key codes but what I used a function to move it for me, the code looks like it should work there is probably just a silly error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Return To Alnerwick</title>
            <style>
               body
                 {
                    background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e8/d6/fc/e8d6fc15671a05eeaf592f85c6dbb2db.jpg");
                    background-size: 1500px 1000px;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                 }

               img
                 {
                    position:absolute;
                    TOP:650px;
                    LEFT:750px;
                    width:100px;
                    height:100px
                 }
            </style>
            <script>
               function move() {
                  var element = document.getElementById("char");
                  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 90 + 'px';
               }
            </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           <img id="char"src="/New Piskel (5).gif">
           <button onclick="move();">move</button>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Move the script tag to just below the `</body>` tag (standard best practice)

Comment: @daniel0mullins it still does not work

Comment: it also looks like you're missing a space between the id and src attributes... I'll try putting this into a fiddle and see exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @daniel0mullins ok thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using a stylesheet. When using a stylesheet, you have get the computed styles:

```
function move() {
     var element = document.getElementById("char");
     var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
     console.log("Current value: " + style.left);
     element.style.left = (parseInt(style.left) - 90) + 'px';
}
```

See a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgb7tc03/1/

Also `getComputedStyle` reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

In your `move` function, you are referencing `element.style.left`. This is the element's inline style property. That inline style property is not defined in your markup at all.

You are defining the `LEFT` property in your css (not inline). What you will need to do is either reference the `LEFT` css property from your function, or set the `left` property inline in your element instead of in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that element.style.left won't return its position. There are a couple of solutions:

1) You know that your image is already 750px from the left so you can just go

```
var img_left=750;
```

at the beginning of your script tag and then go

```
img_left=img_left-90;
element.style.left = img_left + "px";
```

in your function.

2) if you want to get the position of the element, you would go

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

instead of element.style.left so the whole line would be

```
element.style.left=(element.getBoundingClientRect().left-90)+"px";
```

Comment: Solution 2 is the better option, more flexible